# Showing and Hiding Certain Tabs depending on StripMenu Input (C# Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application with multiple tabs. I want to show/hide certain tabs depending on which "mode" the application is in. The mode is selected by the user using the menu drop down item. Here is my code so far.

```
    private void endUserToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabDiagnostics.Hide();
        tabConfigFile.Hide();
        tabTrimConfigFile.Hide();
        tabMemory.Hide();
    }

    private void diagnosticsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabDiagnostics.Show();
        tabConfigFile.Show();
        tabTrimConfigFile.Show();
        tabMemory.Show(); 
    }
```

When I click on the menu items, nothing happens. As usual, pretty inexperienced with C#/WinForms so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? What is a type of tabDiagnostics and others.

Comment: Oh ok! Let me bring up that code hold on

Comment: You have to remove the TabPage from the TabControl's TabPage collection.  Use the TabPages.Insert function to add them back into the correct position.  Removing a TabPage does not dispose of it, but in your case, you probably want to keep it alive.

Comment: @LarsTech I'll give that a shot. Could you put that as an answer so I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TabPages have to be removed from the TabPages collection of the hosting TabControl:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Remove(tabPage3);
```

Removing a TabPage does not dispose of it (although it will be hidden from the screen), but in your case, that seems to be what you want, since you want to be able to add it back in:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage3);
```

or to insert in a particular index:

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(2, tabPage3);
```